# How to decode JSON in a loop using PHP and json_decode?

Tags: php, json

I have json like this, returned from service:

```
{
    "reports" : {
        "name" : "reports"
        "response" : {
            "build" : {
                "version" : "2.55.10.0",
                "name" : "reports-app"
            }
        },
        "status" : 200
    },
    "static-application" : {
        "name" : "static-application"
        "response" : {
            "app" : {
                "name" : "client-frontend",
                "description" : "Client Static"
            },
            "build" : {
                "version" : "2.55.10.0",
                "name" : "client-frontend"
            }
        },
        "status" : 200
    },
    "static-help" : {
        "name" : "static-help"
        "response" : {
            "app" : {
                "name" : "client-frontend",
                "description" : "Client Static"
            },
            "build" : {
                "version" : "2.55.8.0",
                "name" : "client-frontend"
            }
        },
        "status" : 200
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to decode it with json_decode:

```
<?php

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://domainname/api/aggregate/info');
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $data = json_decode($json, true);
        echo $data['reports']['name']." | ".$data['reports']['response']['build']['version']."<br \>";
        echo $data['static-application']['name']." | ".$data['static-application']['response']['build']['version']."<br \>";
        echo $data['static-help']['name']." | ".$data['static-help']['response']['build']['version'];
?>
```

In return i have:

```
reports | 2.55.10.0
static-application | 2.55.10.0
static-help | 2.55.8.0
```

Everything works, but when the service will return more modules, I will have to manually add new echo sections.

How can I write the same in a loop?

Comment: To some extent the answer depends upon HOW the API will return data about multiple modules. Can you show us how the JSON will look in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a [`foreach`](https://php.net/foreach) loop to iterate over all `$data`'s modules:

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data as $module => $data)
{
    if(isset($data[$module]['name']) && !empty($data[$module]['response']['build']['version']))
    {
        echo $data[$module]['name']." | ".$data[$module]['response']['build']['version']."<br \>";
    }
}
```

The `foreach` let you iterate a single element at a time, without the need to manually handle how many elements it contains.

The [`empty`](https://php.net/empty) function checks for the presence of the key in the array and if it contains, in the case it may be missed or empty.

Comment: Does this actually work, have you tested this? Don't you get `PHP Notice:  Undefined index` when running this code?

Comment: It may not throw that Notice, assuming the json will have the key for each module, in any way now there is the check.